Cannot connect ftp on local LAN
I have looked at a lot of the posts on SU and also on regular searches but still cannot connect via Filezilla or Win 10 ftp explorer.
I have double checked all my iis details and they seem correct and I get the green 'All okay' Authent and Authorization in 11s Basic Settings Connection Tests.
Have also checked the permissions for the folder I have assigned for the ftp and the user name and pwd are all correct.
Router and firewall okay fort ftp 20 as 21 was router taken.
I see on posts where the hostname|username need to be entered however my hostname is just hpradioftp and I have to enter the LAN IP 192.168.20.95 in FZ and it will not accept the |username with the IP.
With Firewall closed I get Status:  Connecting to 192.168.20.95:20...
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Firewall open (to test)
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Status: Plain FTP is insecure. Please switch to FTP over TLS.
Command:    USER ftp-radiodj
Response:   530 Valid hostname is expected.
Error:  Could not connect to server
In Explorer I get the panel..
Win cannot access folder. Make sure filename and permissions correct. Details:  A connection with the server could not be established.
I have tried so many things and done what posts suggest but still no glee..
Any help please?

The server seems to require the hostname to be specified as part of the username (not the other way around).

Thank you for your help.  With the firewall open to test  Filezilla gives this which is a better result thus far...
Status: Plain FTP is insecure. Please switch to FTP over TLS.
Command: USER HPstarliteftp|ftp-radiodj
Response: 331 Password required
Command: PASS *********
Response: 530 User cannot log in.
Error: Critical error: Could not connect to server
